# chrome webdriver fails when run from linux docker container with errors [1594905471.000][SEVERE]: bind() failed: Cannot assign requested address (99)]

Tags: docker, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Scenario:

1. Running tests from docker container, in docker container.

Results:
Tests fail with below errors:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
(unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
(The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

T E S T S
Running org.hobsoft.docker.mavenchrome.BrowserTest
Starting ChromeDriver 84.0.4147.30 (48b3e868b4cc0aa7e8149519690b6f6949e110a8-refs/branch-heads/4147@{#310}) on port 16079
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
[1594905471.000][SEVERE]: bind() failed: Cannot assign requested address (99)
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.28 sec <<< FAILURE! - in org.hobsoft.docker.mavenchrome.BrowserTest
canDuck(org.hobsoft.docker.mavenchrome.BrowserTest) Time elapsed: 1.274 sec <<< ERROR!
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
(unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
(The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: '3cf859c01b07', ip: '172.17.0.2', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.19.76-linuxkit', java.version: '1.8.0_252'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
remote stacktrace: #0 0x55bb64b8aea9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Root cause: Cause lays in trying to launch a browser in the container.

Fix: Launch selenium in headless mode in your tests.
For Java, this is shown as below.
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions().setHeadless(true);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

Results: Now tests run successfully, without any errors.